# Extjs Permission Management

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would ask which a best way to manage Extjs Components from database table without make Ajax request for each time we reload page . because I make with Ajax request but I had seen that it take a timeout to disable a button .

thanks

Comment: how large is the dataset?

Comment: Not so large , just I take a component action and I test it if it's permeted IN JSON form : { action : 'todo' , permission : 'true'}

Comment: I would normally download all permission info in a single AJAX request or at page load.

Comment: Thats what I do , But a user can see a laps of time that button is activate when ajax request get response !! i search how I can remove this laps of time

Comment: In some cases a Load mask could help. http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/demos/Ext.Panel.setLoading.1/